# BottomNavigationView Text Resize Animation Issue based on theme used

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

I am using BottomNavigationView but observing a strange issue.

When used with the theme `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`, Text and Icon Resize animation works fine on each item when clicked.

But When used with theme `"Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"`,
it's not working, No Resize animation happening.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#212121"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_color_state"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_main"/>
```

**nav_item_color_state.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_feed"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="List"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_info"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
        android:title="Info"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_profile"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:title="Profile"/>
</menu>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<!-- Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar -->
```

Comment: because `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as of `AppCompa`' was specifically introduced to support animations

Comment: @AbdulKawee - What should use then if my activity uses MaterialComponent theme.? Should i change to AppCompat then?

Comment: yes I think you should go for `AppCompat` and as it has all the needy animations plus styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the properties `app:itemTextAppearanceActive` and `app:itemTextAppearanceInactive`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="#212121"
app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_color_state"
app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_color_state"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_main"/>
```

In `styles.xml`

```
<style name="BottomNavigationView" 
   parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

  <style name="BottomNavigationView.Active" 
  parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
  </style>
```

There's no need to set theme for this View, these styles will do the thing.

Comment: Not working with current app theme "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: did you try adding this style to this bottomnavigationview, as a custom style , and you can apply any theme to your activity which won't affect this view's theme

Comment: Yes. Tried after adding that attribute. I had tried that before posting question,too. But it's not working

Comment: This worked. But is it because of some issue in their styling or it's intentionally kept that way without animation support.
Do let me know if there is any specific theme to use to solve this. (y)

Comment: @bhumik I don't know whether that's an issue with the library, it should've worked when we apply theme to that view. Please upvote the answer if it's helpful to you.